# Numpy rint: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc rint

Tags: python, numpy

is this the expected behavior?

```
import numpy as np
a = [1.1, 2.6]
np.rint(a, dtype=np.int32)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc rint
```

This works:

```
np.rint(a).astype(np.int32)
```